# Can I make the python code work while sorting list

Tags: python, sorting, discord.py

I did a top command on discord.py (using Replit database). Basically shows the top 10 users with the most XP in the server.

That's how a part of my code looks like, ignore my messy way of saving keys to the database

```
@commands.command()
async def top(self,ctx,nr:int=1):
      match_keys = db.prefix(f"{ctx.guild.id}XP")
      sort = sorted(match_keys, key=lambda x: db[x],reverse=True)
[...]
```

**I have like 2000 key to sort**, this whole thing takes about 10 seconds to finish. In those 10 seconds, the bot is unusable. I have tested out and the only thing that takes time is the sort. I saw other similar questions on StackOverflow but from what I found there, the sort/sorted method is based on quicksort, I can't really do much about it to be faster.

I am thinking of making a task loop which will update the top once in a while (less time to wait when running the .top command), but the bot will be unusable while it sorts the list.

Is it possible to slow down the sort so I could use the bot while the operation? Thanks!

sorry for potential mistakes, I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: what is `db`? what does `db[x]` do?

Comment: Sorting 2000 elements in itself should be nearly instantaneous, but it's going to entail calling your `key` function more than 2000 times so if that `db[x]` lookup is slow the sort will be too.  (To prove how fast sorting is, run `sorted(reversed(range(2000)))` -- nowhere near 10 seconds, right?)

Comment: @Macattack db is the predefined way of getting values from the database. If I save a key named "XP" in the database and I give it the value 23, when I call db["XP'] it should retrieve the value 23. However the db[x] in my code is the custom key of sort. `key=lambda x:db[x]` means that for every X item in the list, it will sort for the database value of the X (if the list is {"XP", "cactuses"}, it will sort for the values of db["XP"] and db["cactuses"]. The database thing is not relevant for the question but I hope I helped somehow

Comment: @Samwise ohh so the database is the problem. I'll go make some tests. Thanks for this tip

Comment: @Samwise mmm no, sorting an iterable with X items will only result in your key function being called X times.

Comment: Without going inside the implementation I'd just assume it's being called N log N times, but if it caches it that's certainly nice.  Regardless, if it's slow, sort gonna be slow.

Comment: @DenisDenis 2000 database queries that each fetch exactly 1 item is going to be very slow. Instead you should do *one* query to (pre)fetch *all* items and then use those in-memory values for the `key` function.

Comment: I'm guessing from the naming and usage that the Replit db is being used, which doesn't seem to have any support for multi-key/batch gets. There's support to dump the entire database to a dictionary (you're limited to 5000 key:values in the db) so that could be faster. Kinda killing a fly with a shotgun though, but if that's all you've got.

Answer (score 1):

As I learned from the comments, your database doesn't support multi-key/batch queries. However, there are still some approaches you can take, like [caching](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools), [awaitable remote procedures](https://github.com/choleraehyq/aiorpc), dumping the whole database, etc.

A quick solution could be that you separate querying the database from sorting the entries giving you the possibility to use an async function - and not to block the whole ten seconds.

```py
async def get_entries(match_keys):
    entries = {}
    for key in match_keys:
        entries[key] = db[key]
        await asyncio.sleep(0) # yield control to the event loop
    return entries
```

```py
@commands.command()
async def top(self, ctx, nr:int=1):
      match_keys = db.prefix(f"{ctx.guild.id}XP")
      entries = await get_entries(match_keys)
      sort = sorted(entries.items(), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid blocking the event loop (and thus an `async` application) with long-running, synchronous tasks it is straightforward to offload them to a thread. In fact, `asyncio` already has a builtin thread pool which can run such tasks.

Since Python3.9, [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) makes this convenient:

```py
import asyncio

@commands.command()
async def top(self,ctx,nr:int=1):
      match_keys = db.prefix(f"{ctx.guild.id}XP")
      sort = await asyncio.to_thread(
          sorted, match_keys, key=lambda x: db[x], reverse=True
      )
```

Earlier versions can use `asyncio`'s [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) instead:

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial

@commands.command()
async def top(self,ctx,nr:int=1):
      match_keys = db.prefix(f"{ctx.guild.id}XP")
      loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
      sort = await loop.run_in_executor(
          None,
          partial(sorted, match_keys, key=lambda x: db[x], reverse=True),
      )
```